# svn : how to create a branch from certain revision of trunk

Tags: svn, branch

The following action will only create a branch from the head revision of the trunk. How do I  create a branch from a specific revision? Thanks.

```
$ svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
       http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
  -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."
```

Comment: Just to note that the two backslashes (\) are there to ignore newline characters... and it's not part of the svn command

Comment: Note: the -r REV and url@REV syntax are [not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591967/4669135).

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Check out the help command:

```
svn help copy

  -r [--revision] arg      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
```

To actually specify this on the command line using your example:

```
svn copy -r123 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
    http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch
```

Where `123` would be the revision number in trunk you want to copy. As others have noted, you can also use the @ syntax. I prefer the clearer separation of the revision # from the URL, personally.

As noted in the help, you can replace a revision # with certain words as well:

```
svn copy -rPREV http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
    http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch
```

Would copy the "revision just before COMMITTED".

Comment: Also, in the example above, if revision `123` did not occur underneath `trunk`, then the `copy ...trunk@123 ...` syntax may fail with `Path ...trunk@123 does not exist in revision 768` (where `768` is the repo latest), whereas `-r 123` will do the right thing.  Observed with older SVN clients, may or may not still be the case with 1.6.

Comment: The argument -rREV does not always work. Sometimes you need @REV. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591938/svn-copy-r-revision-number-url-path

Comment: -r works with svn, version 1.7.13 (r1516569) on Mac OS X via Homebrew.

Answer (score 37):

```
$ svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk@192 \
   http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
   -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."
```

Where 192 is the revision you specify

You can find this information from the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), specifically [here on the page about svn copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.copy)

Answer (score 20):

append the revision using an "@" character:

```
svn copy http://src@REV http://dev
```

Or, use the -r [--revision] command line argument.

Comment: Thanks for this. Couldn't tell if the square brackets from the man page were required. Should have figured they were using EBNF.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one:

```
svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk@rev-no 
       http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch 
  -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."  --parents
```

No slash "\" between the svn URLs.