# svn copy -r [revision number] [url] [path]

Tags: svn

So, I've done this before and I just can't seem to figure out what's broken this time...

I'm trying to restore a file from SVN. I went and found the revision where it was deleted (or at least last existed. I verified by using svn list -r)

Here is my command:

```
svn copy -r 925 url/to/repo/foldername htdocs/foldername
```

I keep getting an error:

```
svn: '/!svn/bc/973/.../htdocs/templates' path not found
```

From my understanding that means its looking in revision 973 (which is HEAD) instead of 925.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This same problem exists with other svn commands, such as `svn ls`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
svn copy url/to/repo/foldername@925 htdocs/foldername
```

From `svn help copy`:

```
usage: copy SRC[@REV]... DST
```

See [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html).

Using `-r REV without @REV` means "the ancestor (revision REV) of the current file" while `@REV` without `-r rev` means "the file at REV". This semantic difference is significant because svn tracks copies (and renames).

Comment: Perfect - that did it. Not only was it the right answer, but very timely. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add my +1 if you can provide an explanation of why it's wrong to use `-r XYZ` instead of `url@XYZ` (maybe this is an svn bug?).

Comment: @RichardHansen: I think the only reason is "Because that's the way it works."  I think the SVN project has been moving toward being more forgiving in these areas, and in fact the latest version _is_ much more forgiving about -c vs. -r, etc... I don't know if they've made that particular change or not, though.  For an official answer for "why?" I think you'd have to ask the Subversion development team.

Comment: I found an explanation:  [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html).  Short version:  Using `-r REV` without `@REV` means "the ancestor (revsion REV) of the current file" while `@REV` without `-r rev` means "the file at REV".  This semantic difference is significant because svn tracks copies (and renames).