# How to solve below scenario related to svn branching?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

**My Project structure is like this,**

```
Trunk/X/
Trunk/K/
Trunk/X/Y
Trunk/X/Z
Trunk/X/Y/A
Trunk/X/Z/B
```

I created the branch with particular `X/Z/B` folder.

**My Branch structure**

```
X
X/Z
X/Z/B
```

I have made some changes in the branch and committed to the branch. **Now due to some reason, i need full project(Trunk) in the same branch**. Please understand that there is some difference in code in my branch and i want to retain it. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want trunk of particular revision in branch X.

For that you can create new branch of all trunk from a revision number(which is used for branch X creation) & merge branch X to newly created branch.

You will get all your code in one branch.

To create new brach [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331841/svn-how-to-create-a-branch-from-certain-revision-of-trunk)